# Blocking Sms in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to block an `sms` message from my app in such a way that `sms` does not goes to the inbox and notification is also not shown. Is it possible? if yes how this can be done? any clue or hint would work.

Comment: What have you searched so us your findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with DjHacktorRebeborn's answer, but you can achieve this case by writing your own `BroadCastReceiver`.

You need to write a code for which will keep track on receiving SMS and move those SMS to another location.

However by default SMS will come in Inbox only.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible unless your app has high priority and installed before system messaging app